# ReactJS.NET MVC HTML helpers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs, html-helper, reactjs.net

Is it possible to use mvc html helpers with react, I understand how you would do it traditionally however since the html elements are being generated through javascript this gives me the impression that you cannot do this?  Although I could be wrong.  I have tried searching around but could not find much.

Answer (score 3):

If you generated JavaScript on the fly (like directly into a `script` tag in the HTML with the `type="text/jsx"` and you were OK with using the not-recommended for production in-browser JSX to Javascript compiler (`<script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>`), you could use some of the helpers.

However, I'd suggest it would be far better to use a JSX pre-compiler to convert the JSX syntax to JavaScript and execute that in the browser. ReactJS.NET has one built in that you can use. Also, since JSX supports a number of modern EcmaScript 2015/Javascript features, you may not get the full JSX support by using helpers alone.